# Could not resolve hostname ERROR when adding public ssh key to the server, through Ubuntu 14.04 terminal

Tags: github, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Chromebook. After generating a public/private RSA key pair using $ ssh-keygen, I then want to add they key to the repository using

```
$ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub gituser@git.server.com
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.server.com: Name or service not known

Can you explain the error to me? Thanks!

I'm new to github and besides confirming my terminal commands I don't know what to try. My goal here is to get a remote repository up and running, so I can start coding.

Comment: Look like your git server is down or its hostname is not registered with DNS

Comment: Thanks. I think i figured out that the problem was the remote origin was not correctly setup so I couldn't link to the SSH key...but it's all a bit fuzzy to me.